# Whatever happened to CWI?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

Season 4, like Season 3 of *House of Cards*, has no mention of Claire's non-profit *CWI*. Neither has it ever been mentioned whether the organization was dissolved, sold off or changed hands.

Was there ever a reference made to *CWI* either off screen or onscreen by the cast as to its current status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end of Season 1, Claire fires Gillian Cole who then sues Claire and the CWI for wrongful termination. At the beginning of Season 2, Claire makes a deal with Gillian whereby Gillian drops the suit and becomes the director of CWI (with Claire stepping down).

Answer (score 4):

Also, Claire (as candidate for VP in Season 4) mentions CWI in an interview: she says she can bring experience to the table, as she ran a major non-profit organization. That sounds as if CWI was still running.

Comment: In that episode, Claire simply mentions that she once ran CWI, while making no reference to the current status of CWI.